# iPhone, iPad and BlackBerry emulator for Windows

Tags: windows-7, iphone, ipad, blackberry, emulator

Is there any iPhone, iPad and BlackBerry emulator for Windows? Freeware.

Answer (score 6):

The iPhone (applicable to iPad as well) SDK include a simulator that runs the iPhone OS on your desktop. This allows you to run iPhone apps you have written and test web apps you have developed.

There is nothing else available that will emulate the iPhone as exactly as the iPhone simulator, however it is only for Mac.

Research in Motion makes the Blackberry Device Simulators available for free. I use them on my Windows PC. There is no one device simulator however, you have to download the simulator you want for your model.

Comment: The Iphone SDk only runs on MAC OSX. I need emulator for Windows

Comment: Yes, the iPhone SDK will only run on Mac. I specified that in my answer. There is no other emulator of the operating system available on any other platform - the link posted by eidylon is a UI simulator.

Comment: Will the simulator allow you to run programs that you download?

Comment: No, it's for applications you develop.

Answer (score 3):

Try this guy: [MobiOne](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/) .

> MobiOne Studio - the iPhone app and web app designer and iPhone test center with iPhone emulator that enables you to create, customize and run iPhone user interfaces in minutes, not days.

Comment: +1 (good link but a little advice) Just a link is not a very good answer, you need to put in a little context (so I did so). Ideally you should put in enough information so that you know what's on the other end of the link. In this case there was no way to know if the link was to iPhone/iPad/Blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone/iPad SDK comes with iPhone and iPad emulators. No clue about Blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry comes with emulators for different models. These work nice on windows but if you're not developing an application it's not going to be much use to you.

The same goes for iPhone, you can run it on a mac with Xcode but don't think you'll get iPhone functionality on your PC ;)