# iPhone/IPod App Desktop Emulator

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone, iPad and Blackberry emulator for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/146858/iphone-ipad-and-blackberry-emulator-for-windows)

I want to sell my iPod Touch and buy an Andriod-based phone.  However, there are some apps that I have paid for that are only from the iTunes app store where there is no good alternative on Andriod systems (eg. language learning apps with thousands of words, "references" applications).

Is there a program to emulate the apps that I have already purchased (the ones in my \iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications directory) and play them on my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you purchase the apple developer package it includes a emulator, but this developer package was $99 last I checked.  That's the only way I'm aware of to get the official emulator.

Comment: Will that let me run apps that I purchased?  I thought that's only for apps that you are developing/have the code for. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bill - The SDK & the emulator is free. The price tag is only if you wish to sell it on the AppStore. Not sure if you can run the apps that you purchased.