# Running ipod touch apps on a desktop

Tags: ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone, iPad and Blackberry emulator for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/146858/iphone-ipad-and-blackberry-emulator-for-windows)

I noticed that when my ipod touch is connected to my desktop, iTunes backs up the programs. Can these programs be run on a PC or on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They certainly won't run on a PC - it's a completely different processor architecture and operating system.

I don't know enough about Macs to say for certain about them, but I don't think they'll run on Macs either. The operating system is different & the processor is too. In fact modern Macs run on virtually the same CPU as PCs.

Comment: the CPU in a Macintosh has a lot more in common with the one in your PC than it does with the one in the iPhone.