# How to emulate mobile os on pc

Tags: virtualization, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone, iPad and Blackberry emulator for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/146858/iphone-ipad-and-blackberry-emulator-for-windows)

Do you know of any other os that could be virtualized in a computer using applications like virtualbox and vmware player?
Like this [one](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/) from howtogeek:

And also [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22681/test-drive-webos-without-buying-a-phone/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in the N900, try Scratchbox, it is meant as a SDK but it contains the environment too. I think you can even find it as a package in the Ubuntu repositories.

Just remember that you won't be able to judge the usability and the speed of any OS this way, and when you're on the road, these may count more than functionality.